# Fill geographical column using a .csv and active-record-postgis-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, csv, postgis

I'm trying to fill my **location** column (which is a PostGIS geographical column) using a .csv file to get lon/lat values and active-record-postgis-adapter to query the database using Ruby code.

I already have a short SQL code that works to fill my column but i'm using lon/lat values from the db (and not the .csv file)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(my_table.longitude, my_table.latitude), 4326)::geography")
```

How could I take the lon/lat values from each row of the .csv and put it in the **location** column ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can't avoid filling first a staging table with your csv data, and then copy and transform the lat/lng into points to fill your table.

So, the wole process in SQL would be :

```
-- Create table for staging your data 
CREATE TABLE public.staging
(
   lat double precision, 
   lng double precision
);

-- Copy data from CSV into staging - adapt the delimiter
COPY staging FROM '/abs/path/to/your/file.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';';

-- Transform and copy to your table
INSERT INTO my_table (location) 
  SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng, lat), 4326)::geography 
  FROM staging; 

-- If not needed any more, drop staging table
DROP TABLE staging;
```

And you need to adapt this process if you have other columns.